# Matlab speed problems

Tags: matlab

Can anyone help to understand what/where is the problem?

I am comparing the speed of a basic matlab function like the mean.m with two matlab version 2013b and 2014b with the same machine.

and surprising, the version 2013b is much faster than 2014b.... 
Some of you have/had the same problem??

Profile summary of mean with 2014b --> 0,024 
Profile summary of mean with 2013b --> 0,013

like in my scripts I use the mean function really often the different in running time of the same program in one or the other version is huge.....
Whats going on?

the code to compute the profile time:

```
A=rand(100,1)
 time_mean=zeros( 1000,1)
for i=1:1000
 tic
 mean(A);
 time_mean(i)= toc;
end
```

Comment: Are these results consistent when you make `A` larger?

Comment: You should rather put the `tic` and `toc` outside of the for loop and measure the time it takes to do 1000 calculations instead for one.

Comment: Thanks!  A=rand(1000,1). The profile time for the mean function with  2014 was 0,031, and with 2013 was 0,021...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, it's not wise to use the profiler to compare timings across releases - it's designed to identify slow portions in a single MATLAB release. Secondly, you should use [`timeit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) to time this sort of thing. I compared R2013b and R2014b on my Windows machine over a range of sizes, and can see what appears to be a small fixed overhead in R2014b of around 0.1ms.

Code is essentially:

```
for exp = 1:6
    A = rand(10^exp, 1); 
    t(exp) = timeit(@()mean(A));
end
semilogy(1:6, t);
```

[image: Plot of execution time for vector mean]

If you are making lots of individual calls to `mean`, you might be better off seeing if you can form these into a single call - MATLAB's `mean` can operate down columns or along rows of a matrix...

Comment: Thanks Edric, In fact Im try to increase the speed of a big code for imaging analysis, and by doing the Profile with both Matlabs I found a huge difference in time due to  the `mean´ function (most of the functions for basic imaging analysis call to 'mean' several times) . Like I  assumed that the speed is better (or not worst) from new to old versions. Did you find more basic functions with this difference is time across matlab versions?   Many thanks for your advice